# read form vars via c# webservice from php curl

Tags: c#, php, curl

Hello
i'm trying to read form elemets sent from curl lib in another server, 
in c# , i don't have any idea how to read this vars , 
i'm php developer , but i needed to use some C# writen web service
i mean if it was php not c# this will be my code :

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
```

but here in C# i really don't know how to receive these vars

thanks for any help

Comment: reading input variables is the only your concern? the rest C# code is not a problem for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ASP.NET website, you conld use .ashx generic handler and in it:

```
var x = context.Request.QueryString['<name comes here>'];
```